# Register EventListener after rerender

Tags: javascript, html, event-handling, dom-events, addeventlistener

Imagine you have the following html site:

```
<div id="body">
  <div>
    <form id="form">...</form>
    <div>Foo</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Submitting the form ends up in fetching html content from localhost via `XMLHttpRequest` and replacing the `body` with this content:

```
<div>
  <form id="form">...</form>
  <div>Bar</div>
</div>
```

Sample JS:

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
var form = document.getElementById("form");

xhr.addEventListener("load", function () {
  document.getElementById("body").innerHTML = xhr.responseText;
});

form.addEventListener("submit", e => {
  e.preventDefault();
  var formData = new FormData(form);
  xhr.open('POST', 'http://localhost/update');
  xhr.send(formData);
  form.reset();
}, false);
```

In this scenario the first submit will work as expected. But after the first submit the `EventListener` does not work anymore since its not bound to the current DOM-Element.

**Whats the best approach to get a permanent `EventListener`?**

Comment: best approach.... do not replace the entire document....

Answer (score 0):

In the response of this function, you are replacing everything that exists within **body** tag, including the **form** that is with the event.

```
xhr.addEventListener("load", function () {
  document.getElementById("body").innerHTML = xhr.responseText;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem is the innerHTML instruction.

If you create the form element dinamically, it should work fine. Like this:

```
//do not use this
document.getElementById("body").innerHTML = ....

//use this instead
var form = document.createElement('form');
//put your request inside a custom function
form.onsubmit = yourfunction;
document.getElementById("body").appendChild(form);
```